# Why does If Else statment not output anything?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

Attempting to have the user input four numbers, where they are, and their destination. Then have the output which direction they will be heading.
No matter which values I enter the same thing happens. How can I make the code use the results of the prompts?

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var number=prompt ("What is your current Latitude?");
var number=prompt ("What is your current Longitude?");
var number=prompt ("What is your destination Latitude?");
var number=prompt ("What is your destination longitude?");


var intCurrentLatitude = 0;
var intCurrentLongitude = 0;
var intDestinationLatitude = 0;
var intDestinationLongitude = 0;

if ( (intCurrentLatitude<=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude<=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "We'd be headed North East, capt'n!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude<=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude>=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
    output.textContent = "Ye'd best head North West, captain!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude>=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude>=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South West, captain!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude>=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude<=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South East, captain!";
}
else{
output.textContent = "Land Ho!";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>More if</title>

<body>
 <div id= "output">


 <div id= "input2">
    </div>

</body>


<script src="moreif.js"></script>
<script src="moreif2.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: A hint: 4 variables, all zero

Comment: *"seems to be doing nothing"* is not a proper technical problem description. Any errors thrown?

Comment: It is doing exactly what you told it to do - nothing.

Comment: Side note: `prompt()` returns string values. You'll need to convert them if you want number values. [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: See my answer. I think I figured out what you want.

Comment: Sometimes this need some TDD with all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kept changing the number value and prompt returns a string. Use `parseFloat` to convert a decimal in string form to a number. You did not use the result of the prompts.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var intCurrentLatitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your current Latitude?"));
var intCurrentLongitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your current Longitude?"));
var intDestinationLatitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your destination Latitude?"));
var intDestinationLongitude = parseFloat(prompt("What is your destination longitude?"));

if ( (intCurrentLatitude<=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude<=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "We'd be headed North East, capt'n!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude<=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude>=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
    output.textContent = "Ye'd best head North West, captain!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude>=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude>=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South West, captain!";
}
else if ( ( intCurrentLatitude>=intDestinationLatitude) && (intCurrentLongitude<=intDestinationLongitude) ) {
output.textContent = "Ye'd best head South East, captain!";
}
else{
output.textContent = "Land Ho!";
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>More if</title>

<body>
 <div id= "output">


 <div id= "input2">
    </div>

</body>


<script src="moreif.js"></script>
<script src="moreif2.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the code is doing exactly what it's supposed to. Each of your conditions are asking if a variable is "less than or equal to zero".

The variables you're testing are all at 0, so the first condition fulfills and your program exits.